# Angular Bootstrap DropDown button does not load the data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Im trying to load data into DropDown control but it doesnt load please find the code below

code in Java script file

```
 var employeeEntries = Employee.query(function () {    
            $scope.Employeedata = JSON.stringify(employeeEntries);            
            $scope.Employeedata = employeeEntries;
            console.log($scope.Employeedata)
            console.log($scope.Employeedata[0].employee_firstname)
        });

  $scope.setAction = function (action) {
            $scope.selectedAction = action;
        };
```

Code in my HTML file

```
   <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">{{Employeedata.employee_firstname}}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="emp in Employeedata  track by $index">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setAction(action)">{{emp.employee_firstname}}    </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and the data i see after logging is

```
                    [{
                                 "id":1,
                                 "employee_firstname":"Prabhakar",
                                 "employee_lastname":"Vijendar",
                                 "created_at":"2016-04-28T12:02:28Z",
                                 "updated_at":"2016-04-28T12:02:28Z",
                                 "employee_contact_number":998046,
                                  "employee_email":"testr@gmail.com",
                                  "employee_designation":"Project Manager",   
                                  "employee_address":"Bangalore"
                        },          
                        {
                                 "id":2,
                                 "employee_firstname":"Sai",
                                 "employee_lastname":"Kumar",
                                 "created_at":"2016-05-05T11:58:30Z",
                                 "updated_at":"2016-05-05T11:58:30Z",
                                 "employee_contact_number":789456123,
                                 "employee_email":"sai.kumar@gmail.com",
                                 "employee_designation":"SSE",
                                 "employee_address":"Velore TN India"
                  }]
```

Please find the uploaded image it has screen shot with data been logged[image]

Comment: does `console.log($scope.Employeedata[0].employee_firstname)` actually log what you want? is it `{{Employeedata.employee_firstname}}` that does not work? Because `Employeedata` is an array, it doesn't have a .employee_firstname property

Comment: Yes it prints the data what i expect

Comment: i have used ng-repeat to iterate through array and display the empname but it doest gets loaded

Comment: if you can make a plunkr that shows your problem i will look at it. I think it is the way your data is formatted https://plnkr.co/edit/aE6TOqXUfXmoN5BJywJK

Comment: I agree, it looks like you want `emp in Employeedata[0]` based on what got logged.  But that would mean you'd need to be logging `Employeedata[0][0].employee_name` to see things correctly.

Comment: after converting the objects to json string using stringify i get an exception as         [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: emp in Employeedata